# Can't validate user attempt

Tags: laravel-5, basic-authentication

I'm using `laravel 5.0` and I can't validate the login.
If I type a wrong match of email/pass, it redirects me perfect.
But when I type a correct email/pass then it returns me this:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\User given ...

I'm following the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication) and it looks like everything is allright.

#### Model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {  

}
```

#### Controller

```
public function postsignin(Request $request)
    {
        if( Auth::attempt( ['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password'] ] ) )
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

No idea what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to implement the AuthenticatableContract and Authenticatable trait

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract{  
    use Authenticatable
}
```

Comment: Worked. Could you tell me why ? Documentation has nothing of what you said, and the tutorial I'm following is not using it neither.

Comment: user model should already implemented that out of the box , but looks like that you wasn't have it i don't know why, and already notice the exception that you have get, although look at this in [github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/app/User.php)

Comment: I created the model by command line, don't know why it's not already implemented =\

Comment: you should only get it when you have a fresh install of laravel